# Fraction as a power in siunitx

Tags: fonts, siunitx

For a long time I have used the following code to put the fraction 1/2 as an exponent on the unit:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\DeclareSIPostPower\rooted{\sfrac{1}{2}}

\begin{document}

\sfrac{1}{2} \unit{\s\rooted}

\end{document}
```

However, this no longer works and I get bunch of weird errors.  This is probably because `siunitx` was changed substantially in recent times.  What should I do to keep using fractions as the exponent?

Possible alternative could be to use `\textonehalf` from `textcomp`, but that does not work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Updated answer after realizing that `\sfrac` can be used in both text mode and math mode.)

I'd give `\unit{\second\tothe{\text{\sfrac12}}}` a try.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{siunitx,xfrac}

\begin{document}
\unit{\second\tothe{0.5}} \quad 
\unit{\second\tothe{\frac12}} \quad
\unit{\second\tothe{\text{\sfrac12}}} \quad
\unit{\second\tothe{\text{$\sfrac12$}}} \quad
\unit{\second\tothe{\text{\textonehalf}}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 Thanks! The last one is just good enough.  Still `sfrac` and  `textonehalf` are smaller.  Hopefully someone provides solution with them.

Comment: @Pygmalion - Speaking for myself, I find that the result of `\unit{\second\tothe{\text{\textonehalf}}}` looks awful. Incidentally, you may prefer the look of `\sfrac{1\mkern-2mu}{2}` over that of the basic `\sfrac{1}{2}` expression.

Comment: Oh, only now I see `\sfrac12` is the same as `\sfrac{1}{2}`...  `\sfrac12` is smaller than `$\sfrac12$`.  Why?

Comment: @Pygmalion - It's only now that I realized that `\sfrac` can be used in both text mode and math mode. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Yes `\sfrac` without `$$` is perfect!  However, when I use `\unit{\m\per\s\rooted}` I get bunch of errors.  Should I open a new question for that?

Comment: @Pygmalion - Did you run `\DeclareSIPostPower\rooted{\sfrac12}` or `\DeclareSIPostPower\rooted{\text{\sfrac12}}`?

Comment: With \text.  And I get:
`<argument> \???  
                 ! LaTeX Error: Erroneous variable \protect used!
l.23 \unit{\m\per\s\rooted}`  It seems that `\per` is the culprit.

Comment: @Pygmalion - I have no idea what's going on with `\rooted`. I'll remove that reference from the answer. I do know that `\unit{\second\tothe{\text{\sfrac12}}}` works fine.

Comment: Yes, but `\unit{\meter\per\second\tothe{\text{\sfrac12}}}` does not work.

Comment: I am pretty sure this is some kind of bug in `siunitx`.  I'll accept your answer and open a new one.